# Errors not printing using custom PrintStream even after setting System.setErr()

Tags: java, multithreading, console

Basically, I wanted console to do 2 things:

1. I wanted console to color code errors and general info messages (which errors being red and everything else green).
2. I wanted to save all console messages to a log file.

So, I created a print stream that looked something like this:

```
public static class GeneralStream extends PrintStream {

    public GeneralStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(String string) {
        String time = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now());

        String output = "["+time+"] ["+type.n()+"] "+string;
        Logs.logToFile(output);
        
        String coloredOutput = ANSI_RESET+ANSI_WHITE+"["+ANSI_CYAN+time+ANSI_WHITE+"] "+
                ANSI_WHITE+"["+ANSI_RESET+type.c()+type.n()+ANSI_WHITE+"] "+type.c()+string+ANSI_RESET;
        super.println(coloredOutput);
    }
}
```

Great. Then I set this print stream at the start of my program as the default PrintStream using:

```
// Set console output settings
    System.setOut(new Console.GeneralStream(System.out));
    System.setErr(new Console.GeneraStream(System.err));
```

Awesome. Finally, upon doing System.out.println("Hello World"), I get the result I expected. My messages are colored. They are logged to a file. Great! In fact even if I do System.err.println("Error!"), I still get a result as expected. **However, "automatic" exceptions do not print through the System.err that I set**.

Here is an example:

```
// Set console output settings
    System.setOut(new Console.GeneralStream(System.out));
    System.setErr(new Console.ErrorStream(System.err));

    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    System.err.println("Printing an error!");

    // Real exception (NPE)
    Integer nullInteger = null;
    System.out.println(nullInteger.toString()); // won't print and will produce a NullPointException
```

Here is the result:
[As you can see, my System.out and System.err print fine but as soon as there is a real exception, it prints regularly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B5Un.png)

So my question is how can I set a custom PrintStream for errors like this so they are logged to a file (and preferably follow my custom message formating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into how the `Throwable` class prints the stack trace, you'll see it uses the `println(Object)` method, so you'll need to add this method to your custom ErrorStream class:

```
@Override
public void println(Object object) {
    println(String.valueOf(object));
}
```

Even then, you may want to change the "uncaught exception handler" to change how it logs exceptions. It seems that the default handler calls first `System.err.print` to output `Exception in thread "{ThreadName}"` followed by `Throwable.printStackTrace`, so you end up with the time stamp and other stuff in the middle of the message. For example:

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread, throwable) -> {
        System.err.println("Uncaught exception in thread " + thread.getName());
        throwable.printStackTrace(System.err);
    });
```

Comment: What about if there are multiple threads in the program? Would you have to do this for every single thread?

Comment: The JVM has one single global "default uncaught exception handler" that's why  `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` is static - but if you have threads or thread groups with custom exception handlers you would have to examine what they do one by one

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated!